# Function to play two sounds at the same time (C)

Tags: c, arrays, function

```
void layer1and2 (NoteData input)
{
    while(!feof(textFilePointer2))
    {

        float frequency[2];
        float amplitude[2];

        amplitude[0] = input.velocity/127.0;
        amplitude[1] = input.velocity/127.0;

        frequency[0] = 440 * pow(2, (input.notes-69) /12.0);
        fscanf(textFilePointer, " %d %d\n", &input.notes, &input.velocity);
        frequency[1] = 440 * pow(2, (input.notes-69) /12.0);
        fscanf(textFilePointer2, " %d %d\n", &input.notes, &input.velocity);
        printf(" %d %d\n\n", input.notes, input.velocity);
        aserveOscillator(1, frequency[0], amplitude[0], 0);
        aserveOscillator(0, frequency[1], amplitude[1], 2);
        aserveSleep(500);
        aserveOscillator(1, 0, 0, 0);
        aserveOscillator(0, 0, 0, 0);


    }

}
```

Hi, I'm new to programming so please go easy on me.
This part of my program is a function to playback two sequences at the same time using different oscillators. I'm not sure that I'm going the right way about it? 
At the moment the note information is gathered from 'textFilePointer2', but I need to get note data from 'textFilePointer & textFilePointer2' at the same time!
Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're a little vague in the particulars, but I'm guessing that the problem is that textFilePointer and textFilePointer2 are being fed data in real-time and that having one file descriptor with no data causes the program to block, despite the fact that the other has something that is ready to play.

One way to do this is to open the files, instead of with stdio's open, which returns a FILE* with all the goodies like fscanf, use the system call:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>

void layer1and2 (NoteData input)
{
    int flags = fcntl(fileno(textFilePointer), F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(fileno(textFilePointer), F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
    flags = fcntl(fileno(textFilePointer2), F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(fileno(textFilePointer2), F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
```

Now, reads on textFilePointers will not block:

```
int retval;
retval = fscanf(textFilePointer, " %d %d\n", &input.notes, &input.velocity);
```

If fscanf returns -1, then there was no data to be read from textFilePointer and you can ignore input.notes and input.velocity. If the return value was 0, then the scan pattern didn't match the input data (imagine doing an fscanf("%d") and the first thing in the input was "abcde".) When fscanf returns a positive value, it's the count of scanned items:

```
if (retval > 0) {
    /* Set your oscillator here */
}
```

This is probably the simplest way to go about it, but you might also find what you need if you look up select(). I find select() to be a bit confusing to many novices with file descriptors, so see if setting the flag works for you first.